# Make [passbook] a synonym of [wallet]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

With the introduction of iOS 9, Apple renamed "Passbook" to "Wallet".

On SO, we have the tags [passbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/passbook) and [wallet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wallet). AFAIK, there were no major changes for developers that came along with the change of name, so I think it is unnecessary to have both tags. Since "Wallet" is the current name, I would propose to make "Passbook" a synonym of "Wallet".

As mentioned in the comments, it would also be a good idea to rename the [wallet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wallet)-tag to [apple-wallet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-wallet) to avoid confusion with "Google Wallet".

Comment: Given the other wallets, such as Google Wallet, if we do this it should be Apple-Wallet to reduce confusion

Comment: I prefer neither. Just remove this thing. Use instead [tag:passkit-api].